# Mejorar codigo y no tener tantas lineas

Tags: php, array

Hola espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo mi pagina php, en la cual lleno una tabla con datos.
Son exactamente 16 datos, y cada uno llama a su consulta.
Esto funciona perfectamente, pero quisiera resumir codigo ya que mi codigo esta asi actualmente:

```
<?php
  $rb1 = $consulta->reservab1($fechaActual);
  $trb1=$rb2->fetch_object();
  $Totb1=$trb1->b1;
  $Br1=$trb2->u1;

  $rb2 = $consulta->reservab2($fechaActual);
  $trb2=$rb2->fetch_object();
  $Totb2=$trb2->b1;
  $Br2=$trb2->u1;
    
  $rb3 = $consulta->reservab3($fechaActual);
  $trb3=$rb3->fetch_object();
  $Totb3=$trb3->b1;
  $Br3=$trb3->u1;
.
.
.
?>
```

las cuales llaman a estas consultas ( tambien de 1 a la 16)

```
        public function reservab1($fecha)
    {
        $sql="SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(*)*100)/8,0) as b1,8-COUNT(*) as u1 FROM `tbltabla` WHERE id=1 and fecha='$fecha'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
        public function reservab2($fecha)
    {
        $sql="SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(*)*100)/8,0) as b1,8-COUNT(*) as u1 FROM `tbltabla` WHERE id=2 and fecha='$fecha'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
        public function reservab3($fecha)
    {
        $sql="SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(*)*100)/8,0) as b1,8-COUNT(*) as u1 FROM `tbltabla` WHERE id=3 and fecha='$fecha'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
.
.
.
```

asi hasta el dato 16, y obviamente en la tabla lleno con los datos $Br1, $Totb1...hasta el $Br16, $Totb16

Se que debe de existir una forma de hacer todo mas compacto.
Intento con un bucle de for, pero no se como manejar los nombres de las variable o el nombre de la funcion

Muchas gracias

Comment: Cuales son las consultas ?? Que hace reservabN() ?? hay muchos detalles por aclarar, pero parecen 3 consultas diferentes, las cuales no se si puedes hacerlas juntas con un join

Comment: listo ya la inclui :)

Comment: O sea me estas diciendo que estas haciendo la misma consulta 16 veces ?? No podrías traerte las cosas hasta el 16 de inmediato ?

Comment: Asi es. Soy nueva en ese tema, por eso pido ayuda para mejorar el codigo :)

Comment: Podría, basta agregar id a los campos de salida y cambiar la cláusula where. De todas formas el problema de rendimiento es menos importante que mala práctica que introduce vulnerabilidades de [Inyeccion SQL](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:
Creas un for para que haga el llamado de las consultas, sin necesidad de escribir el código 16 veces:

```
for($i= 1; $i <= 16 ; $i++){

  ${"rb".$i}   = $consulta   -> reservab($fechaActual, $i);
  ${"trb".$i}  = ${"rb".$i}  -> fetch_object();
  ${"Totb".$i} = ${"trb".$i} -> b1;
  ${"Br".$i}   = ${"trb".$i} -> u1;

}
```

Si te fijas agregué un parámetro a `reservab` (y de hecho le cambie el nombre).

Bueno, ahora vamos a la parte de las consultas. En tus consultas realmente lo único que cambia es el ID, así que podemos pedir ese ID como parámetro (el for nos va a dar los números del 1 al 16) y se lo concatenamos:

```
  public function reservab($fecha, $id){
      
        $sql="SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(*)*100)/8,0) as b1,8-COUNT(*) as u1 FROM `tbltabla` 
              WHERE id=$id and fecha='$fecha'";
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
      
}
```

y con eso te evitas repetir el mismo fragmento de código 16 veces.
Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Meter las variables así en la consulta es una pésima práctica que da lugar a problemas de seguridad. El OP debería incluir más detalles y la respuesta usar un binding que evite [inyecciones SQL](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta , es justo lo que queria hacer, mejorar el codigo.

Comment: el OP pidió como reducir las lineas de código, no como mejorar la seguridad. Aunque es cierto que se pueden cambiar las sentencias con PDO, eso ya sería cuestión para otra pregunta.

Comment: me alegro que te funcionara!

Comment: De todos modos esta solución no es óptima, pues ejecuta `N` consultas en la base de datos, lo cual es más costoso. Es mejor una sola consulta que traiga las filas del rango requerido, en este caso, entre los ids 1 y 16.

Comment: No se como maneja la info una vez que se trae de la base de datos, no se si la guarde en un arreglo, si la muestre directamente, no se si el 16 va a cambiar en algún momento, no se muchas cosas sobre este código. Una vez más, yo simplemente respondí a lo que El OP solicitaba. Si, se pueden traer los 16 datos en una sola consulta en vez de en 16 diferentes, pero probablemente eso haga que otra parte del código deje de funcionar. Así que por eso lo propuse así, y parece que al OP le funcionó. En tema de optimización, bueno eso ya es aparte.

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta ejecutar 16 o `N` consultas por separado, cuando puedes obtener todas las filas que necesitas en una sola consulta, escribiendo así un código optimizado, pues la base de datos va más ligera ejecutando una sola consulta (que arroja `N` resultados) que ejecutando `N` consultas para obtener `N` resultados. Es como si necesitaras un reporte de 500 empleados y ejecutaras 500 consultas para obtener cada fila de empleados... esto no tendría sentido en base de datos.

#### Función modificada y optimizada

La función quedaría así:

```
public function reservab($fecha, $fromId, $toId){
    $sql="SELECT 
           TRUNCATE((COUNT(*)*100)/8,0) as b1,
           8-COUNT(*) as u1 
          FROM `tbltabla` 
          WHERE 
              id >= $fromId AND 
              id <= $toId AND
              fecha='$fecha'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

Esta consulta te devolverá ya las `N` filas que mades a buscar y las puedes imprimir o hacer lo que quieras con ellas.

#### Ejemplo de llamada y de lectura de resultados:

```
#El 1 y el 16 son los límites que quieres, del 1 a 16
$mData=reservab($fechaActual,1,16);

while ($obj = $mData->fetch_object()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $obj-b1, $obj->u1);
}
```

#### P.D.:

- Si necesitas otro tipo de uso puedes decirlo en comentarios a esta respuesta.
- La función podría adaptarse también para criterios complejos, pasando un array o algo parecido.
- **Advertencia de seguridad**: Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir este riesgo.